# How to disable "Warn me then closing multiple tabs" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

This option in firefox does not work for many, I read. But at least it did not asks me if I want to close all tabs. Now after the recent update, it asks me every time, even when I disable this option.

I use in imacro **TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS** command, and now the macro can't go on because of this confirm box.

Is there any way to disable this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I made a quick workaround by using greasemonkey and window.close command. Still would be nice to find this out, i'll take a look there thank you

Answer (score 6):

In Firefox 26.0 the annoying warning on closing multiple tabs appeared for "me too" so this still seems to be a source of frustration...

**What fixed it for me:**

1. Browsed to the magic `about:config` page.
2. Searched for options containing "`warnOnClose`".
3. Set both these options to false:

   ```
   browser.tabs.warnOnClose           false
   browser.tabs.warnOnCloseOtherTabs  false
   ```

**What did not fix it for me:**

Unchecking the preference checkbox:

```
    Edit > Preferences > Tabs > Warn me when closing multiple tabs
```

Resetting Firefox:

```
    Help > Troubleshooting Information > Reset Firefox
```

Comment: yes, marking browser.tabs.warnOnClose = true worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This is still not working in Firefox 31 on a Mac. The preferences setting makes browser.tabs.warnOnClose false but has no effect on browser.tabs.warnOnCloseOtherTabs. But editing about:config does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed now. Try the latest version of Firefox (16.0.1 as of the time I write this post).

Comment: I have 16.0.2 and it's not fixed yet.

Comment: Strange. It works fine for me. What OS do you have? (I'm not sure this is necessary to know, but...)

Comment: Windows 7 ultimate 64. The only way I could get rid of the problem was by installing the [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) extension.

Answer (score 1):

Get the [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) extension. That's how I got rid of it when nothing else worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is annoying.

According to

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=277079

it was changed the way that the dialog always comes  - regardless of the option in Preferences->Tabs->"Warn me when closing multiplbe tabs".

It is said that it'll be fixed in a later version.

In the meantime you may use the "Close All Tabls (Reloaded)" addon.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the annoying tabs all together! unter tools - optons- tabs: uncheck all but warn me if new tab would slow down ffx. solved all my tab problems by having them gone.IZ